# Проверка массива на то, что он не пустой, и в нём есть только числовые значения

Tags: php, массивы

Мне нужно, чтобы возвращался `0` в случае, если массив пуст или есть не числовые значения.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

function mid(array $arr = []): int
{
    return array_sum($arr) / count($arr);
}

echo mid([]);
```

Я пробовал добавить

```php
if (empty($arr)) {
    return 0;
}
```

Это сработало, но я так и не смог найти как проверить массив на наличие текста.

Comment: 0b1 и 1e3  считаются числовыми значениями?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы проверить массив на наличие нечисловых значений, вы можете использовать функцию `is_numeric` для каждого элемента массива. Если хотя бы один элемент не является числом, то функция вернет `false`.

Вот пример кода:

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types = 1);

function hasNonNumeric(array $arr): bool
{
    foreach ($arr as $element) {
        if (!is_numeric($element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function mid(array $arr = []): int|float
{
    if (empty($arr) || hasNonNumeric($arr)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return array_sum($arr) / count($arr);
}

echo mid([]); // Выведет 0
echo mid([1, 2, 3]); // Выведет 2
echo mid([1, 'two', 3]); // Выведет 0
```

В этом примере добавлена функция `hasNonNumeric`, которая проверяет каждый элемент массива на то, что он не является числом. Если хотя бы один элемент не является числом, функция вернет `true`, в противном случае вернет `false`. В функции `mid` добавлена проверка на наличие нечисловых значений в массиве перед подсчетом среднего значения. Если такие значения есть, функция вернет `0`.

Comment: empty() тут лишнее. если уж мы используем strict_types, то лучше и проверку написать явно, $arr === []

Comment: Только надо помнить про буквы b, e и пробелы. 0b11111 и 1e3 считаются в РНР числами. как и любое число, окруженное пробелами

Comment: А что выведет `echo mid([10,15,18])`?

Comment: Ну вот кстати да, верное замечание, с типом автор вопроса лажанулся, здесь надо было его поправить

Answer (score 1):

Элементы массива можно проверить на предмет - число ли это - с помощью функций `is_int()` и `is_float()`. Как вариант - с помощью `gettype()`, но писать больше.
Тип возвращаемого значения функции лучше сделать `float`, т.к. в общем случае результатом деления станет дробное число. Ну или использовать функцию `intval()`, чтобы не возникло ошибки типов при возврате дробного частного.

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

function mid(array $arr = []): float
{
    if (count($arr)==0) return 0;
    foreach($arr as $el) { 
        if (!(is_int($el) || is_float($el))) { 
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return array_sum($arr) / count($arr);
}

echo mid([10,15,18]),"\n";
echo mid(["10",15,20]),"\n";
echo mid([]);
?>
```

```
14.333333333333
0
0
```

Можно было бы применить `is_numeric()`, но она выдает истину, когда аргумент - строка, которая представляет собой число.

Comment: Я понимаю, что хочется написать покороче, но сейчас никто не пишет в одну строчку, тем более - на публику.

Comment: @Ипатьев Сейчас никто и для себя не пишет в одну строку `if else or return`, напоминает какой то сжатый JS. Банально читать и редактировать этот код неудобно, максимум можно сократить до тернарных операторов.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = исходные данные;
$filteredArray = array_filter($array,  fn($item) => is_int($item) || is_float($item));

if ($array === [] || $array !== $filteredArray) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему вы все так не любите массив $_POST? Да и $_GET, если уж на то пошло

Comment: Как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: Самым прямым образом. Оба этих массива всегда будут для вашей функции пустыми

Comment: @Ипатьев исходя из вопроса и что ТС считает сумму через `array_sum`, видно, что он оперирует нумерованным массивом, а не ассоциативным.

Comment: да при чем здесь это. в этих массивах никогда не бывает ни целых, ни дробных чисел, только строки. Ну и в целом для РНР, если речь идет о "числовых значениях", то числовые строки подразумеваются по умолчанию.

Comment: @Ипатьев *"да при чем здесь это"* --- самым прямым образом при чём. Т.к. POST и GET - ассоциативные и текущий код работает с нумерованным массивом. Будь хоть миллион раз POST GET иметь возможность передавать целые числа - код рассчитан на нумерованность............ *"числовые строки подразумеваются по умолчанию"*  --- не извращайте данность. Числовые строки - это всё равно строки...... Считаю остальная беседа не имеет смысла. Если только ТС не подтвердит какие-либо факты, которые необходимы для него

Comment: Но у автора-то нигде не написано строки. У него написано "текст". А насчет массивов $_POST и $_GET - если вы думаете, что через них нельзя передавать нумерованные массивы, то у меня для вас две новости :)

Comment: Впрочем, если они вас так отталкивают, можно забыть про текстовый протокол HTTP и взять цены, полученные из mysql. В реальном, а не воображаемом мире, числовые строки в РНР - это числа.

Comment: Но вообще я наверное зря придираюсь. Раз стоит strict_types, то надо считать, что числа уже приведены к нужному типу